# Sending a NSMutableURLRequest request with "Body Requests"

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube-api

I'm currently working with YouTube API and allowing users to subscribe to other channels, however now I'm supposed to send a POST method that includes a "Request Body".

Here's the Request that's I'm supposed to send :

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=snippet&key={YOUR_API_KEY}


//The Request Body

{
 "snippet": {
  "resourceId": {
   "channelId": "UCJZ7f6NQzGKZnFXzFW9y9UQ"
  }
 }
}
```

Here's my current code

```
+(void)subscribeToChannel:(NSString *)channelID {
    GTMOAuth2Authentication *auth;
    auth = [GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch authForGoogleFromKeychainForName:kKeychainItemName clientID:clientIDclientSecret:clientSecret];


    NSString *urlStr;
    NSMutableURLRequest *request;        
    urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?id=%@&key=mykey", channelID];

    [request setHTTPBody:[@"{ \"snippet\": { \"resourceId\": { \"channelId\": \"UCJZ7f6NQzGKZnFXzFW9y9UQ\" } } }" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
    request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];


    [auth authorizeRequest:request
         completionHandler:^(NSError *error) {

             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,
                                                      (unsigned long)NULL), ^(void) {


                 NSString *output = nil;
                 if (error) {
                     output = [error description];
                     NSLog(@"ERRO LOADING INFO : %@", output);
                 } else {
                     NSURLResponse *response = nil;
                     NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                                          returningResponse:&response
                                                                      error:nil];

                     if (data) {
                         output = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                                        encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

                     } else {
                         output = [error description];
                     }
                 }



             });
         }];
}
```

I'm positive that I'm doing something wrong in **[request setHTTPBody]** but that's the only thing that I could think about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're attempting to set the `NSMutableURLRequest`'s HTTPBody before you have allocated an instance of `NSMutableURLRequest`.

```
    NSString *urlStr;
    // The request is nil
    NSMutableURLRequest *request;        
    urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?id=%@&key=mykey", channelID];

    // At this point the request is still nil so you are attempting to set the HTTPBody on a nil object
    [request setHTTPBody:[@"{ \"snippet\": { \"resourceId\": { \"channelId\": \"UCJZ7f6NQzGKZnFXzFW9y9UQ\" } } }" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]
```

You also mentioned in a comment that you are receiving a "This API does not support parsing form-encoded input." error. You may be receiving this error because you are not setting the content-type (I came to this conclusion from googling the error. I may be wrong).

This should work:

```
    NSString * urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?id=%@&key=mykey", channelID];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
    NSMutableURLRequest * request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    // Set the content type
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    // Create the dictionary that you will be using in the HTTPBody
    NSDictionary * httpBody = @{
                              @"snippet": @{
                                    @"resourceId": @{
                                            @"channelId": channelID
                                            }
                                    }
                              };

    // Make sure that the above dictionary can be converted to JSON data
    if([NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:httpBody])
    {
        // Convert the JSON object to NSData
        NSData * httpBodyData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:httpBody options:0 error:nil];
        // set the http body
        [request setHTTPBody:httpBodyData]; 
    }
```

I do this when bumping places using the Google Places API, but it should work the same.

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm now getting this error message though : "Required parameter: part" :(

Comment: Silly me, I just forgot to add ?part=snippet in the url.

Comment: I make simple mistakes all the time too, no worries. I'm glad it's working for you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
NSMutableDictionary *channelId = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[channelId setObject:@"UCJZ7f6NQzGKZnFXzFW9y9UQ" forKey:@"channelId"];
NSMutableDictionary *resourceId = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[resourceId setObject:channelId forKey:@"resourceId"];

NSDictionary * postDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:resourceId forKey:@"snippet"];

NSError * error = nil;
NSData * jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:postDictionary options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
[request setHTTPBody:jsonData];
```

Comment: Still not working :(, I think you're going the right way though.

Comment: "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "parseError",
    "message": "This API does not support parsing form-encoded input."
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "This API does not support parsing form-encoded input."
 }
}